# how to freeze the state of the component 1 on going back to it from component 2

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

In my Angular Application I am trying to freeze the state of the component one when I go to **component 2** and again come back to **component 1** .

Details -:

- In **component 1** there are **6 tabs**
- when I click to **any tab** and go to another page/component ,
- then when I go back to the **component 1** . always  **tab 1** is opening .
- **Where I want that , clicked tab should open when I go to the component 1 from component 2.**

I tried to solve my issue using **RouterState** and **RouterStateSnapshot** , but Actually it didn't worked 
because , we have same route eg. https://xyz/ on selecting any tab , so we can't reflect it in route

Comment: There should be route fragments e.g hash fragment for each tab (#tab1,#tab2 etc) You can access the fragment by subscribing to the ActivatedRoute.fragment Observable

Comment: Create a service which will maintain the state of the tab that was opened. When you go back to the component, use the same service to get the tab which was clicked before and make it active programmatically.